# How can I use a proof I've made in Idris to inform the compiler that my type signature is correct?

Tags: idris, proof-of-correctness

I have a function count in idris, defined as :

```
count : Eq a => a -> Vect n a -> Nat
count x [] = Z
count x (y::ys) = with (x == y)
  | True = S (count x ys)
  | False = count x ys
```

And a proof of the maximum value count can return:

```
countLTELen : Eq a => (x : a) -> (l : Vect n a) -> LTE (count x l) n
countLTELen x [] = lteRefl
countLteLen x (y::ys) with (x == y)
  | True = LTESucc (countLTELen x ys)
  | False = lteSuccRight (countLTELen x ys)
```

which is all well and good. I now want to write a function which removes all of an element from a list, removeAll :

```
removeAll : Eq a => (x : a) -> (l : Vect n a) -> Vect (n - (count x l)) a
removeAll x [] = []
removeAll x (y::ys) with (x == y)
  | True = removeAll x ys
  | False = x :: removeAll x ys
```

But this definition gives an error:

```
   |
56 | removeAll : Eq a => (x : a) -> (l : Vect n a) -> Vect (n - (count x l)) a
   |                                                          ^
When checking type of Proof.removeAll:
When checking argument smaller to function Prelude.Nat.-:
    Can't find a value of type 
            LTE (count a n constraint x l) n
```

How can I use my proof to inform Idris that this type signature is correct?

Comment: 1) `countLTELen` is not necessary here, I think. 2) I’d use a `Fin n` for the output of `count`, but it doesn’t really matter. 3) I don’t have the ability to write out a full answer, but if you replace the two RHSs of the `with` block with holes, you should see that you only need some basic proofs about `(-)`.

Comment: @HTNW Sorry, I should've been more clear- this definition gives a type check error, which I've now included in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, Idris can't find the proof `{auto smaller : LTE n m}` for `(-)`.

So either you need to be explicit:

```
removeAll : Eq a => (x : a) -> (l : Vect n a) ->
                    Vect ((-) {smaller=countLTELen x l} n (count x l) ) a
```

Or, because `smaller` is an `auto`-argument, you can hint the compiler to your proof function. Then this function will be tried when `auto`-finding a value for `LTE (count x l) n`.

```
%hint
countLTELen : Eq a => (x : a) -> (l : Vect n a) -> LTE (count x l) n
```